# Changing the Database Path in Codename one

Tags: ios, sqlite, codenameone

Is there any way to change the Database path in codename one other than the default path which is creating automatically. I need to get the database out from the ios device and check it.

But in the ios device am not getting the **path/** folders which the database is creating in default path.

I tried to create the database externally , the db is created but i can't access the file: The command i used to create db externally is.

```
String DbPath =FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath()+"Test.DB";
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(DB_PATH);
```

but when i tried to access the db am getting error

```
 Database db= db.getDatabasePath(DbPath);
```

Expecting a Solution!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before opening the database use `Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath(dbName)` this will return the file path where the database is saved and you can copy that file.

Comment: but in my case it saving in the path in ios device as /var/mobile/Applications/F90B8C3F-15E9-4120-966C-57270FCA2EA4/Documents/Test.DB how can i copy this.. i can't retrieve this path in my ios device.

Comment: You need to copy files via code or use something like the send email API to send this as attachment. iOS doesn't expose the local filesystem to users.